# android open url and change fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, fragment

I am trying to open a link using intent.action_view in android.
but I want to change the fragment I am in right after this link is opened.
For example, I will switch from fragmentA to fragmentB and open the url with the following code under fragmentB onCreateView method.

```
val browserIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
startActivity(browserIntent)
```

but FragmentB appears on the screen for a short time until it is directed to the url. After the FragmentA I want, the url should open, when I return to the application, fragmentB will be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to **give parameters to fragmentB (give `Boolean` : show activity)** or show fragmentB before and call fragmentB method, for example "fragmentB.showActivity()".

Looks like there is a better solution for this kind of problem.